# How to get personal account Id in SOQL or rest request?

Tags: email, account, salesforce-id

I need to load account ID of my current user.
I try: SOQL

```
SELECT Name, ID FROM Account where Name = 'myMailUsedForLogin';
```

and result is:

```
Sorry, no records returned.
```

I think I should load current account data by different restriction, may be using different sobject...

### Could you please help or fix my request?

Comment: What defines a personal account id in your org?

Comment: That is default SF field *Id*.

Comment: Which field are you referring to? You have mentioned you need to "load account id of my current user" -- how have you linked a user to an account id? Or do you mean to say that you have current users as owners of the account and that is what you need here? Or do you want the Id of the logged in User, if that's the case then refer to the answer provided below.

Comment: I know **login**, it is email. Login that's used for authorization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A user account in Salesforce is a [User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm), not an [Account](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_account.htm) (which is a CRM object for tracking business). Further, a user's login is the username, not name (which is your actual *name*). The query you want is:

```
SELECT Id FROM User WHERE UserName='user@company.com'
```

Or, as a REST CALL, you may also:

```
/services/data/v43.0/chatter/users/me
```

Which returns all of your current user info.

Comment: @sfdcfox - I must say, you interpreted the question really well :)

Comment: @JayantDas Thanks. When you've been doing this long as I have, you tend to get better at figuring out intent.

Comment: True, that's where I always say Experience really Matters :)

Comment: @sfdcfox can't we avoid soql here by using `UserInfo.getUserId()`?

Comment: @PragatiJain The question is not marked as Apex, and also explicitly asked for REST, so I presumed use of the API rather than Apex code.

Comment: That makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for retrieving the `Id` of a logged in User, then refer to what [sfdcfox has provided in this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/236365/54851).

However, as I understand to the extent I get from your question, you want to be fetch Accounts which is Owned by the logged in User. If that's what you are looking for, then you should have your query as:

```
List<Account> accountList = 
    [select id, name from account where ownerid = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
```

Comment: Just trying to make sure you got what you needed. And you have the answer now. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UserInfo.getUserId()` to get current logged in user id. Avoid SOQL.
You can access more logged user info using `UserInfo` class. Please check out:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm